# openldap - adding image to 'photo' attribute gives me 'no validator for syntax'

Tags: ldap, openldap

New to openLDAP - i'm trying to simply add a base64 encoded binary (16Kb) image to the `photo` attribute to the person objectClass but whatever i try i simply get this error '**no validator for syntax 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.23**'.

Also changing the ldif to stream the binary image (using `photo: <file:///tmp/t1.png`) also fails with the same error.

I've tried with Apache Directory studio (that takes the binary file and converts it to the base64 representation) but fails with the same error. I'm able to get this working 'with the same base64 text' against the `jpegPhoto` attribute (so this suggests the encoding is well formed) BUT i would simply like understand why it failed for the photo attribute - anyone able to explain? This is a fresh install against the latest OpenLDAP on Centos.

googling this error gives me [Googlewack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Gorman%27s_Googlewhack_Adventure).

Comment: Is it base64 encoded? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829590/edit-ldap-photo-attribute-spring-ldap-invalidattributevalueexception/5829880#5829880

Comment: @GregAskew - it is yes, i've expanded the question to make that back much clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every LDAP server is configured with a *schema* where each LDAP attribute has a specific "syntax". They are not all defined as arbitrary strings or blobs – they need to conform to their syntax, which the LDAP server tries to validate.

The `photo` attribute was originally defined to have an image **specifically** in the CCITT "Group 3 Fax" image format – that's what the [syntax OID](https://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.23) in question means.

(That's why `jpegPhoto` is a separate attribute – it was added later in order to maintain compatibility with older directories and clients, as changing the data type of an existing 'photo' field wouldn't have been a good idea.)

Currently you're getting the error message because the OpenLDAP server doesn't really support this data format at all, but if it did, you'd still be getting a different message about the (JPEG) data not being recognized as G3Fax image data.

You could edit the attribute's OpenLDAP schema to change the data type it accepts (via cn=config) or you could continue using the newer 'jpegPhoto' attribute.

Comment: i think my confusion (that i didn't talk about in the question) is that i'm migrating from apache DS to openLDAP and it didn't complain about images in this attribute..

Comment: Yeah, that's like migrating from MySQL to Postgres – the concepts are the same but the implementation is going to differ. ApacheDS might have a different schema definition for this attribute, it will have different implementation of attribute syntax handling, etc.